# How to Parse 2D NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have following 2D `NSArray` with `NSDictionary`, and I want to parse this array by using `NSPredicate` for  "date","clientName" and "location".

```
 (
            {
        activity =             (
                            {
                city = Denver;
                clientFillId = 811;
                clientId = 733;
                clientName = "1 Stop Shop";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-10 23:48:24";
                endingLBS = 12;
                location = "400 S. Lipan Street Unit 23";
                startingLBS = 0;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 12;
                zip = 80204;
            },
                            {
                city = Denver;
                clientFillId = 812;
                clientId = 527;
                clientName = "1 Stop Shop #2";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-10 23:49:03";
                endingLBS = 55;
                location = "400 S. Lipan Street Unit 6";
                startingLBS = 12;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 43;
                zip = 80204;
            }
        );
        date = "2016-04-10";
    },
            {
        activity =             (
                            {
                city = Denver;
                clientFillId = 813;
                clientId = 733;
                clientName = "1 Stop Shop";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-11 00:01:34";
                endingLBS = 56;
                location = "400 S. Lipan Street Unit 23";
                startingLBS = 55;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 1;
                zip = 80204;
            },
                            {
                city = Parker;
                clientFillId = 814;
                clientId = 10;
                clientName = "20 Mile Tap House";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-11 01:27:58";
                endingLBS = 55;
                location = "12543 N. Highway 83";
                startingLBS = 0;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 55;
                zip = 80134;
            },
                            {
                city = "Castle Rock";
                clientFillId = 835;
                clientId = 11;
                clientName = "212 Pizza Co.";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-11 22:46:19";
                endingLBS = 56;
                location = "848 N. Ridge Road";
                startingLBS = 55;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 1;
                zip = 80104;
            },
                            {
                city = Parker;
                clientFillId = 825;
                clientId = 10;
                clientName = "20 Mile Tap House";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-11 22:51:51";
                endingLBS = 12;
                location = "12543 N. Highway 83";
                startingLBS = 0;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 12;
                zip = 80134;
            },
                            {
                city = "Fort Collins";
                clientFillId = 490;
                clientId = 9;
                clientName = "1933 Brewing Company";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-11 22:52:07";
                endingLBS = 14;
                location = "4025 S. Mason Street Unit C";
                startingLBS = 12;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 2;
                zip = 80525;
            }
        );
        date = "2016-04-11";
    },
            {
        activity =             (
                            {
                city = Denver;
                clientFillId = 838;
                clientId = 733;
                clientName = "1 Stop Shop";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-12 00:33:42";
                endingLBS = 25;
                location = "400 S. Lipan Street Unit 23";
                startingLBS = 0;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 25;
                zip = 80204;
            },
                            {
                city = Denver;
                clientFillId = 496;
                clientId = 764;
                clientName = "2116 Systems";
                endServerDateTime = "2016-04-12 00:34:28";
                endingLBS = 56;
                location = "2116 S. Kalamath Street";
                startingLBS = 25;
                state = CO;
                totalLBS = 31;
                zip = 80223;
            }
        );
        date = "2016-04-12";
    }
);
```

I will use this NSPredicate for searching in UITableview.

This is hierarchy of object "NSArray"->"NSDictionary"->"NSArray"->"NSDictionary"

How i can do this ?

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY activity.location == %@", @"Human"]

Comment: try this one and tell me this work for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263479/how-to-filter-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY activity.location == %@", @"Human"] Is not working

Comment: you have see link which i send you ?

Comment: Thanks i got solution with given link